# Fix container inside another container on window scroll using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container `thisSticks` that I have to `fix` in another container `stickInContainer` on scroll. Basically, replicate CSS `sticky` behaviour. I could have just used `sticky`, but it doesn't work in all browsers. So I am making it in pure javascript.

**Current Behaviour**: In the *demo* below, grey container should never overlap with blue `footer` container, but it does.

**Expected Behaviour**: When the bottom of `thisSticks` hits top of `footer`, it should stay there and when user scrolls back up and reaches top of `thisSticks`, it should stick back to top of `stickInContainer` till it reaches its initial position.

I can think of incrementing `stickyDiv.style.bottom` on every scroll after `thisSticks` bottom hits top of `footer`.

How will this work, Is there another approach?

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction();
}

const stickyDiv = document.getElementById('thisSticks');

const stickyDivHeight = stickyDiv.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > stickyDivHeight) {
    stickyDiv.style.position = 'fixed';
    stickyDiv.style.top = 0;
  } else {
    stickyDiv.style.position = 'initial';
  }
}
```

```css
#topSection {
  height: 100px;
}

#stickInContainer {
  height: 800px;
}

#thisSticks {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: grey;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id='topSection'>Top Section</div>
<div id='stickInContainer'>
  <div id='thisSticks'></div>
</div>
<div id='footer' />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another condition to test when the footer reach the top minus the height of the sticky element. If it's the case you change the `top` differently:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction();
}

const stickyDiv = document.getElementById('thisSticks');
const footer = document.getElementById('footer');

const stickyDivHeight = stickyDiv.offsetTop;
const Height = stickyDiv.clientHeight; /*height of the sticky element*/

const footerHeight = footer.offsetTop; /*footer offset*/

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > stickyDivHeight ) {
    stickyDiv.style.position = 'fixed';
    stickyDiv.style.top = 0;
  } else {
    stickyDiv.style.position = 'initial';
  }
  
  /*Here the sticky will touch the footer and top will be negative*/
  if(window.pageYOffset>(footerHeight - Height)) {
    stickyDiv.style.top = (footerHeight - Height)-window.pageYOffset + "px";
  }
}
```

```css
#topSection {
  height: 100px;
}

#stickInContainer {
  height: 800px;
}

#thisSticks {
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height: 40px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: grey;
}

#footer {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 500px;
}
body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div id='topSection'>Top Section</div>
<div id='stickInContainer'>
  <div id='thisSticks'></div>
</div>
<div id='footer' ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need another condition to check if it hit the bottom of your `stickInContainer`. You can achieve this in different ways, you can check style bottom as you mentioned or footer top maybe, but since you have a container, I have prefered the approach below.

I edited code your a little by defining a limit that points to your container's bottom
`var stickyLimit = stickyDivContainer.offsetHeight + stickyDivContainer.offsetTop  - stickyDiv.offsetHeight`

and added a condition to your into your if block to make `stickyDiv` stop and wait there.

```
  else if(window.pageYOffset>=stickyLimit ){
    stickyDiv.style.position = 'static';
    stickyDiv.style.top = stickyLimit;
  }
```

I hope this is what you are looking for, i also suggest making some transition effect to `stickyDiv` where it changes its position behaviour, because checking scrolls from offset values and making changes to position style doesn't feel smooth.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction();
}

const stickyDiv = document.getElementById('thisSticks');

const stickyDivContainer = document.getElementById('stickInContainer');

const stickyDivHeight = stickyDiv.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {

  var stickyDivBottom = stickyDiv.scrollTop + stickyDiv.offsetHeight;
  var stickyLimit = stickyDivContainer.offsetHeight + stickyDivContainer.offsetTop  - stickyDiv.offsetHeight;

  if (window.pageYOffset > stickyDivHeight && window.pageYOffset<stickyLimit ) {
    stickyDiv.style.position = 'fixed';
    stickyDiv.style.top = 0;
  }else if(window.pageYOffset>=stickyLimit ){
    stickyDiv.style.position = 'static';
    stickyDiv.style.top = stickyLimit;
  }else {
    stickyDiv.style.position = 'initial';
  }
}
```

```css
#topSection {
  height: 100px;
}

#stickInContainer {
  height: 800px;
}

#thisSticks {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: grey;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id='topSection'>Top Section</div>
<div id='stickInContainer'>
  <div id='thisSticks'></div>
</div>
<div id='footer' />
```